# Google maps Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Well i actually doing an app but i dont know how to continue.

I want google map to take all the sites within a range of 300 meters and classify the sites by services like restaurants, shops, etc.

Do u know how to do it?
This is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(0, 0);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title("Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of the Place Search API by Google. 
First, you will need to make a call to the Google Nearby Search API -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=300&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You will get a JSON response in the following format -

```
{
  "html_attributions": [],
  "results": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": -33.870775,
          "lng": 151.199025
        }
      },
      "icon": "",
      "id": "",
      "name": "Rhythmboat Cruises",
      "place_id": "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
      "types": [
        "travel_agency",
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "establishment"
      ],
      "vicinity": "Pyrmont Bay Wharf Darling Dr, Sydney"
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

You can then parse this JSON response and get the information you need.

You can find more information on this at [https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search](http://Place%20Search)

Or, here is a tutorial you can try - 
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-search-nearby-displaying-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-google-maps-api-v2/